# What will be the output of this?

Tags: c

I was doing this question and I have a doubt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int fun (int);
    int i=3;
    fun(i=fun(fun(i)));
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}

int fun ( int i )
{
    i++;
    return(i);
}
```

I have a doubt when it gets to

```
fun ( i = 5 )
```

What happens with this? Will the value of i go to 6 or it will be 5.
According to me, it should be 6. But that is not the correct answer.

Comment: how about running it?

Comment: You don't assign the result of fun(i) when i ==5 to anything, so i isn't updated.

Comment: @MightyPork, this was a theoretical question asked in one of the exams. I can run it easily, but I Want to know the concept behind it. :)

Comment: @user3797829 By running it, you can verify if your guess was correct. If it is, good, if not, you can tinker with the code to find out why you made the mistake.

Comment: Your program's behavior is fully defined by the standard, so running it will answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

**In C, parameters are passed by value.** The variable `i` in the main function is actually different from the `i` inside `fun()`, because its value is copied when it is passed into the function.

When you call `i = fun(fun(i))`, 5 is isassigned into `i` in the main function. However, the call to `fun(5)` that returns 6 does not assign its result back into `i`, leaving it unchanged. When the output is printed, `i` is still 5.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the call to `fun()` is not assigned to `i`. Therefore `5` is expected, not `6`.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to scope. In the function scope, variables defined in that scope or the parameters pass in does not any effect on outer scope variables, unless it is a pointer. So, the output of `fun` will be assigned to `i` in the `fun(i = 5)` but the internal operations of `fun`, do not effect the outer scope `i`. So it stays as it is before `fun` last call.  The output is `5`.